# Rearrange equation with integrating factor

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to do the following in the middle of a huge question involving a differential equation - I need to rearrange this equation for t, but have no idea where to start.

[image: Equation to rearrange]

[image: Result, that is correct with my values (the first is the one I want to rearrange to (or close to)]

First image is the Equation to rearrange
Second image is Result, that is correct with my values (the first is the one I want to rearrange to (or close to)

Any hints on where to go with this - I've tried and tried, but I end up with the integrating factor - (3t+125)^(2/3) on either one side or another.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine $\frac {3t}{5} +25$ to get $\frac{3t +125}{5}$.

The 5 in the denominator is to be used for multiplying $25 + 0.6t$ such that $5(25 + 0.6t) = … = 125 + 3t = u$ for the moment.

The original is then transformed to something not that ugly. Enjoy.